# Difficulties with displaying post information on seperate page

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

I am making a website that you can post things on and the posts show up on your feed, sort of like instagram. Everything works as far as retrieving the posts from the database and displaying them all on one page using a forEach loop. There is a button that says "more details", and when clicked on it brings you to a separate page with just that post on it. 
The problem is that when I try to go to the page, nothing shows up. There are no errors shown either, and the other header info shows.

```
app.get("/posts/:author/:id", function(req, res){
    Post.findAll({
        where: {
            id: req.params.id,
            author: req.params.author
        }
    }).then(function(foundPost){
        var renderPost = foundPost;
        res.render("show", {post: renderPost});
    });
});
```

That is the code for the get request of the page.^

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

<h1><%= post.author%></h1>
<h1><%= post.body%></h1>
<h1><%= post.title%></h1>

hi

<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

That is the code for the actual show page.
The "hi" displays along with 3 empty h1's when you use inspect.

Comment: what module are you using for DataBase queries?

Comment: I am using sequelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the `findAll` method returns an `Array`, so in order to get the post object, you should do:

```
var renderPost = foundPost[0];
```

Comment: At first that seemed to make sense, but after doing it, the "more details" page shows only the name of the post maker.

Comment: After looking at my code for the "more details" page, I realized that the post.title, and post.body do not match up with the names of the columns in the database. I did use the "[0]" on foundPost and it did help me. Thanks for your help.